# Installed TFS 2010, where is SharePoint Management Shell?

Tags: powershell, wss-3.0, tfs

I just did a fresh (single-server) install of TFS 2010, which has all the Sharepoint (WSS 3.0) components.  But I want to move the SharePoint log files to a different drive, and all instructions point to using the "SharePoint Management Shell".

I go to Start menu and there is no "SharePoint" item at all - does anyone know how I can access the Management Shell?  This is on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by installing TFS 2010 using its default settings comes with WSS 3.0. This also means not SharePoint Powershell, only simply PowerShell.

You should uninstall WSS 3.0 (after disconnecting your Project Collections via the TFS Administration Console) and then re-install at least SharePoint 2010 Foundation. If you have already documentation in your sites, simply make sure you backup your databases

Once this is done, you would again via TFS Administration Console, select to connect your project collections to SharePoint, after installing SharePoint Extensions (from TFS installation kit). This would activate 2 solution packages. Make sure you give Farm permissions to your TFS Service, etc. (MSDN guide is quite on that).

There is a lot more to say here, but these steps should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have SharePoint 2010 installation on your Windows Server 2008 if you want to access SharePoint Management Shell

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx

> After installing SharePoint 2010 Products, the applicable Windows
>   PowerShell cmdlets are available by using the SharePoint 2010
>   Management Shell, or by using the Windows PowerShell console. With the
>   management shell, you can manage every aspect of SharePoint 2010
>   Products. You can create new site collections, Web applications, user
>   accounts, service applications, proxies, and more. The commands from
>   the management shell output SharePoint objects based on the Microsoft
>   .NET Platform. These objects can be applied as input to subsequent
>   commands or stored in local variables for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install SharePoint as well, and just aren't seeing the items in the Start Menu? If so, open up a PowerShell prompt and enter the following:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
```

If that returns with no errors, you are essentially in the SharePoint Management Shell now.

Comment: It looks like the TFS install did install some version of SharePoint, I can get into the central administration site.  But maybe it's an incomplete install...

Comment: You should always load the whole signed script in 14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration or at least make sure you load the shell in single thread apparture, since SharePoint mostly doesnt support multithreading (eg `$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"`)